# why does __construct() has such a strange name?

Tags: php, function, constructor

I'm just wondering why is `__construct()` called so. Why isn't it say just `construct()`? I mean maybe there's an interesting reason for that that only a few know because others didn't wonder. I'm sure that someone knows php good enough to explain that.

Comment: Code ≠ Italics. `:)`

Comment: See the second answer.

Comment: I assume you mean the `__`?  That is a convention for _magic_ methods.  Methods that are not called by the program or programmer but by the object when certain things happen. **PHP reserves all function names starting with __ as magical.** http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php